# Why Insert command when button clicked OpenERP

Tags: python, openerp-7

I am working on module. it has a button, its name is creates, as shown in following code.

```
<button name="creates" string="Create" type="object" groups="base.group_erp_manager" />

def creates(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
    for id in ids:
        deg_obj=self.pool.get('deg.form').browse(cr,uid,id)
    pr=int(deg_obj.categg_temp)
    ctx=dict(context)
    ctx.update({'default_pr':pr})

    return{
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'product.product',
        'context': ctx,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'current',
    }
```

when i click this button i get

```
Integrity Error

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: name - name]
```

On my server log i have

```
2014-12-31 08:18:40,566 7407 ERROR new_db openerp.sql_db: bad query: insert into "product_template" (id,"supply_method","list_price","standard_price","mes_type","uom_id","cost_method","categ_id","uos_coeff","sale_delay","procure_method","sale_ok","company_id","produce_delay","uom_po_id","rental","type",create_uid,create_date,write_uid,write_date) values (639,'buy','1.00','0.00','fixed',1,'standard','9','1.000',7.0,'make_to_stock','True',1,1.0,1,'False','consu',1,(now() at time zone 'UTC'),1,(now() at time zone 'UTC'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/sql_db.py", line 226, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
IntegrityError: null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (639, 1, 2014-12-31 08:18:40.463017, 2014-12-31 08:18:40.463017, 1, null, null, 1.00, null, null, null, 0.00, fixed, 1, null, standard, 9, null, 1.000, null, t, null, null, 1, null, 1, 1, f, consu, null, null, 7, null, buy, make_to_stock).

2014-12-31 08:18:40,569 7407 ERROR new_db openerp.netsvc: Integrity Error
The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: name - name]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 174, in wrapper
    netsvc.abort_response(1, _('Integrity Error'), 'warning', msg)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 71, in abort_response
    raise openerp.osv.osv.except_osv(description, details)
except_osv: ('Integrity Error', 'The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:\n- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it\n- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set\n\n[object with reference: name - name]')
```

My first question is. Why I am getting an error with sql insert command although there is nothing like insert related to `creates` method. It simply opens a form where i will press save button or something to save value.
Secondly, how i can bypass this and move to next step where i can create item.

NOTE: I have Edit, View methods and buttons too, which simply opens Value in View and Edit mode. but have same issue with them too.

**Edit**

One thing i must mention. I have `print "\n\n Inside Create Method"`
 in creater method. It is never shown on my server console/terminal.

**EDIT1**
`deg_form` has `_inherit= 'product.product'

Comment: Did you try changing the name of the method?

Comment: What view contains your Create button?

Comment: @PhucTran i changed method's name from creates to creater. Same issue.

Comment: @AndreiBoyanov I have module names system, which has `deg_form` class. Creates method is in `deg_form` class. `deg_form` view has Creates button

Comment: Try remove the `for loop` and change from `deg_obj=self.pool.get('deg.form').browse(cr,uid,id)` to `deg_obj = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)`. I dont know if it works

Comment: I did it, same issue. Please check my edit in question @PhucTran .

Comment: I think this is because your button hasn't recognized the method yet.ie it cannot find the method

Comment: Try commenting the lines before 'return {...'
I tested it in my module and it works just fine...

Comment: Are you able to create new product from the Product menu? Should be the same as what you do in your code...

Comment: @AndreiBoyanov I tried to comment whole method with keeping return in method. I still have same issue. while creating product, i never faced this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this `_inherit='product.product'` in your class is breaking the things.

Your original form (not the one you try to open with the button) is trying to save the object before executing the button's action. As the model this form is dealing with inherits 'product.product', your form is trying to same something in the 'product_product' (and respectively - in 'product_template') tables. I suppose that your form does not supply enough fields to satisfy the required 'product_template' fields.

Are you sure you need the inheritance? It seems to me that you don't need it.

Suggestion: Instead of print() inside your code try using PDB:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

It's very powerful and helps a lot with OpenERP.

Comment: If you have resolved the issue can you please write it here how you solved it? Thanks!